# Кузница или кузня — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

Чаще говорят "кузница", но вчера увидел рекламу местных кузнецов, и там было написано "кузня". А как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В основном значении это синонимы, не имеющие стилистических отличий.
В переносном значении (типа "кузница кадров") используется только "кузница".

Comment: Я понимаю, что комментарий от 2012 года, но. Т.е. вы вводите в некое заблуждение человека. Если нет разницы между Кузней и Кузницей, то. Из ваших слов не будет разницей между Пекарней и Пекарем? Сравнение грубое, но справедливое. И не в обиду людям данной профессии. А точнее выражаясь. Пекарь, как творец Выпечки, будет равен - выпечке. А соответственно Пекарня, будет приравнена к выпеченной продукции. Т.е. Пекарь равен выпечке - правильно?

Comment: Вы путаетесь: кузница, кузня, пекарня — это помещения, а кузнец и пекарь — это люди.

Comment: @SarkasarNeoWorld   1. **КУ́ЗНЯ** -и; мн. род. -зен, дат. -зням; ж. **Нар.-разг. = Ку́зница** (1 зн.). В кузне шумят мехи, летят искры. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/161166/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F  2. Еще: **ку́зня**
ж. местн.
Мастерская или цех для обработки металла ковкой; **кузница** I.  https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/179503/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F  Мне кажется, что Вы спорите не в ту сторону.

Comment: @SarkasarNeoWorld *Из ваших слов не будет разницей между Пекарней и Пекарем?* Вы делаете две ошибки. Во-первых, фактическую. Отношение *пекарня-пекарь* аналогично отношению *кузница-кузнец*, а не "кузня-кузница". Кузнеца ни кузней, ни кузницей не называют. И вторая ошибка - методологическая. Аналогии очень редко что-то доказывают. Сравните кузня-кузница и волк-волчица. По вашей логике должно получится, что кузница - самка кузни. Согласны, что это абсурд?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова у человека русский, видимо, не совсем родной. Боюсь, ваша отсылка к словарю, только запутает без дополнительного комментария.

Answer (score 0):

Синонимичность этих слов в главном, нейтральном, значении неоспорима. Это утверждают все словари: и то, и другое — мастерские для ковки изделий из металлов.

Но цитата из Нац. Корпуса РЯ — «Подошел со свечой в руке к столу приземистому, с ножками, обитому серебром, открыл на средине стола ларец с грузной крышкой: в ларце были золотые вещи ― ожерелья, запястья, кольца, перстни. Вся золотая кузня унизана драгоценными камнями.» (А.П. Чапыгин. Разин Степан. 1927) — показыает, что **кузней** как в древности, так и в XX веке назывались сами произведения кузнечного искусства. В таком смысле у этого слова односложного синонима даже одного не припоминается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]